# "Literary feel" of writing

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, style, predicative-adjuncts

I read on the British Council [website](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/participle-clauses?page=2) how to transform the following sentence  into another structure.

The original sentence was:

> Soaked to the skin, we eventually reached the station.

This was transformed by a person who claimed to be from *The LearnEnglish Team*, the sentence transformed is in bold.

> You can place the participial phrase in a number of positions:
>
> *Soaked to the skin, we eventually reached the station.*
>   *We eventually reached the station, soaked to the skin*.
>   ***We, soaked to the skin, eventually reached the station.***
>
> The last of these would be the least common, and has a rather literary feel.

How can we do this? What kind of sentence structure it is?
It has been said to be literary style, so I would like to know more about this.

Answer (score 3):

"We, soaked to the skin, reached..." is a very unlikely phrase. It is not conversational. In conversation we would hear:

> We reached the station soaked to the skin.
>
> Soaked to the skin, we reached the station.

The participle phrase can be put in several places, and it is not unimaginable that some author would write:

> We, soaked to the skin, reached the station.

However, normally we'd expect there to be some evident reason for separating the subject-phrase from the verb-phrase in that manner.

> The new recruits, trousers dropped to the ankles, shuffled
>   around the army clinic getting inoculated against a variety of
>   maladies.

Comment: But the second version is said to be literal,So,I would like to learn it even though it's unconventional.